# How does the spawning pool work in Goblin Camp?

Tags: goblin-camp

How does the spawning pool work? Is it just that random creature comes out at random intervals or can you affect it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, it is random in what it spawns (Goblin or Orc) and when it spawns.  So far nothings can influence it and you can only have one pool per game/camp.

Build it immediately when you start a new camp.

Comment: As of now I think dumping filth and corpses into it makes them spawn faster. Please review your answer.